How to debug OpenLDAP
We are running an openLDAP server on version 2.5.13 on a Debian Bookworm virtual machine. Since upgrading at the start of the year from version 2.4 (and Debian Bullseye) to 2.5 (and Debian Bookworm) we experienced that sending search querys to the ldap server was quite a bit slower and occasionally timeouts, especially:

SSH Login (using ssh-ldap-pubkey and pam-ldap) takes >15 seconds, sometimes even timeouts
Recently, Zulip also started complaining about timeouts when accessing data that seem to be stored in the ldap server - maybe because they decreased the timeout.
sudo (with sudo-ldap) takes >15 seconds

When upgrading from 2.4 to 2.5, we had to remove certain schemes, which were moved in the core, as described in the upgrading process. So I hope that this change did not decrease performance.
I also couldn't fine any clear error messages on any log I looked at, especially at syslog, auth.log and the ssh -v (but I may have missed one).
Some things I already tried:

Restarted the ldap virtual machine
Checked that indexing is still activated
Specify the port directly
Set REFERRALS no in ldap.conf
removed pam_systemd.so from /etc/pam.d/common-session

Anyone maybe any further ideas, or at least ideas on how to further locate the problem?
Thanks very much!
